# How to cancel all notifications in status bar using NotificationListenerService

Tags: java, android

I want to build an app that will cancel all notifications when they appear. So if some application displays a notification, my app will auto-close it.

How to solve this problem using NotificationListenerService ??

Answer (score 0):

Put below code on onCreate of activity that you are calling on notification click

```
NotificationManager notifManager= (NotificationManager) context.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
notifManager.cancelAll();
```

It will clear all notification.